# mixed model specification for nested variables

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have collected crop yield data from multiple blocks for multiple years and associated rainfall data. Each block is located within a municipality and each municipality is located within a State. I am interested in knowing the relationship between yield and rainfall while accounting for the effect of location and year. This is how I specified my model:

```
lmer(yield ~ rainfall + (1 | block) + (1 | muni) + (1 | state) + (1 + year | block))
```

I am somewhat confused by different way of writing the formula specification and would appreciate if someone could advise me if the above specification is correct? The reason I am asking is because in this [post](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#fn1) I found a specification which suggests to me that model should be specified like this:

```
lmer(yield ~ rainfall + (1 | state:muni:block)
```

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two models you show are not the same because in the former you also have the random slope for `year` in the `block` level. BTW, you don't need both `(1 | block)` and `(1 + year | block)`, the latter is sufficient, i.e.,

```
lmer(yield ~ rainfall + (year | block) + (1 | muni) + (1 | state))
```

Now, check the Section ['Nested or Crossed'](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#nested-or-crossed) of the GLMM FAQ. As you can see in the last bullet-point, there is a difference between the two formulations when the lower-level groups have the same values for the upper-level groups. For example, if in your dataset the `blocks` are coded as {1, 2, 3, ...} within each municipality, then you need the latter type of syntax. If however, they're coded as {1, 2, 3} for municipality 1, and {4, 5, 6} for municipality 2, etc., then the former type of syntax will also work correctly.